# Multiple outputTable in ReactiveStateEngine and TimeSeriesEngine

Tags: dolphindb

I wanted to use multiple `ouputTable` in `ReativeStateEngine` and `TimeSeriesEngine`. How can I use more than 1 `outputTable` in `streamengines`? Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think in DolphinDB, one engine can only output 1 result table. If you want to get multiple output tables, you can use multiple streaming engines, such as cascade. In the meantime, the output table can be subscribed to by multiple engines or subscribers.